# AppCompatCheckBox not working for below API 21

Tags: android, xml, checkbox, android-appwidget, android-checkbox

I created a dynamic checkbox with the following code:

xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_checkbox);

ll.removeAllViews();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    AppCompatCheckBox myCheckBox = new AppCompatCheckBox(getApplicationContext());
    myCheckBox.setText(i);
    myCheckBox.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    myCheckBox.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    myCheckBox.setTextSize(12);

    myCheckBox.setId(i);

    ll.addView(myCheckBox, lp);
}
```

Now from above code only `LOLLIPOP` version shows the checkbox with text. And for below `LOLLIPOP` version it shows only `Text` but not showing the checkbox.

Same thing work with all device if I put the below code in xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Testing"
    android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

But I can't define the checkbox in xml as I have to create it dynamically.

Even `setButtonTintList` is not working for below `LOLLIPOP`

How can I show the Checkbox for below `LOLLIPOP` version with `AppCompatCheckBox` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not use `getApplicationContext()`, for the `Context` passed in to `new AppCompatCheckBox()` you need to use a reference to your activity (that extends `AppCompatActivity`) context for it to correctly inject the styling for the `AppCompatCheckBox`. This will be `new AppCompatCheckBox(this)` if you're creating this in an activity, or `new AppCompatCheckBox(getActivity())` if you're creating this in a fragment.

Code like this below will work on all versions:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =
          new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

      AppCompatCheckBox myCheckBox = new AppCompatCheckBox(this);
      myCheckBox.setText("text");
      myCheckBox.setTextSize(12);

      myCheckBox.setId(i);

      layout.addView(myCheckBox, lp);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will definitely work

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Testing"
                app:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"/>
```